# Mechanism of copying structures in Swift?

Tags: struct, swift

What are the mechanism of copying structures in Swift?

Are structures stored in the same place in memory as classes and they are just immutable classes, or structures have their own place to live and die and have their own copy mechanism?

I have read this article, but it seems to be too advanced: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-07-18-exploring-swift-memory-layout.html